# Add field from parent to every child node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I want to avoid data duplication in my Java code but result xml have to have such duplication.

Is it possible with such java code

```
  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Parent {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "children")
    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    List<Child> children;

    @XmlPath("children/*/surname/text()") //dosn't work
    String surname;
  }

  public class Child {
    String name;
  }
```

get

```
    <parent>
       <children>
          <child>
             <name>Bob</name>
             <surname>FromParent</surname>
          </child>
          <child>
             <name>Sara</name>
             <surname>FromParent</surname>
          </child>
       </children>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using some annotations from (deprecated) JAXB, so I guess you're asking about Java / XML binding.  I'm not sure what `@XmlPath` is supposed to be, howewer -- I guess you just made that up.

In any case, in an XML binding, each class maps to an element type, and each of its fields to an attribute or child element of that element type.  You cannot map to a more deeply nested node, and you especially cannot map to a non-unique node.

So no, what you ask is not supported, nor does it really make much sense.  Consider: what is supposed to happen if Java tries to deserialize a `<parent>` of children who have different `<surname>`s?  If `<surname>` is exclusively a property of `<parent>`, as in your classes, then that's where it belongs in the XML.  If it's a property of each `<child>`, as in your XML, then it should correspond to a property of class `Child`.

Possibly it should be an independent property of each: as a real-world example, my mother has a different surname than I do, and if my daughter ever marries then she will likely take a different surname than mine.  Similar might well apply to analogous situations that are not structly familial.